# How to encrypt in php5 and decrypt in windows store 8.1 and c# using aescbc

Tags: c#, php, encryption, windows-store-apps, aes

Hi guys I have encrypted the word hello in a string in PHP using the AesCbc method. Here is my code.

```
base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,'1234567890123456',pkcs7_pad('hello', 16),MCRYPT_MODE_CBC))
```

The result is

```
67fHA+Z12z2jlwOLTBeCPA==
```

I then send this result to my windows store application and this is the function I use to decrypt it.

```
        public string AES_Decrypt(string input, string pass)
    {
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc);
        CryptographicKey AES;
        HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
        CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

        string decrypted = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] hash = new byte[32];
            Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
            byte[] temp;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);

            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);

            AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));

            IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(input);
            byte[] Decrypted;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(AES,Buffer,null), out Decrypted);
            decrypted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypted, 0, Decrypted.Length);

            return decrypted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The result is this

```
7��t�\a2H\0��g
```

When it should be "hello".
So where am I going wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key isn't hashed in your PHP code. So, don't do it in C#:

```
AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)
));
```